# SQL: Not equal operator Problem

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, vb.net, t-sql

I am using a not equal operator `<>` in my sql statement but it doesn't retrieve any record which is not equal to the selected date.

CODE:

```
 Command = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Products] WHERE [ParkingStartDate] <> @StartDate", myConn)

 Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", StartDate1)
```

Comment: Do you _have_ any records that are different?

Comment: @Oded: +1, @OP: Please run the select query in a sql management studio query window, instead of `@StartDate` insert a date value (such as '1/1/2011'), verify you get no results, then show us the `[ParkingStartDate]` field value from a row you'd expect to have in the results.  If you get results from the query, then the problem has nothing to do with your not equal to operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't return anything if either of the following is true:

- `StartDate1` is a `NULL`
- `ParkingStartDate` for all values is a `NULL` or equal to `StartDate1` (obvious one)

Check that you are passing a non-`NULL` value in `StartDate1` and there are records satisfying your condition.

Answer (score 2):

If the values are null you would have to do

```
Command = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Products] WHERE [ParkingStartDate] <> @StartDate OR ParkingStartDate is null", myConn)

 Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", StartDate1)
```

Answer (score 0):

First stop using that <> operator.

Use instead != (NOT EQUAL)

run this statement in sql. it will return zero results. to illustrate my point.

```
select '1' where NULL <> 0
```

instead use

```
where columname != @startdate or columnname is null
```

Comment: `!=` is not a part of standard. Why using it at all?

Comment: I Agree with you about the ISO standards from msdn "Tests whether one expression is not equal to another expression (a comparison operator). If either or both operands are NULL, see SET ANSI_NULLS (Transact-SQL). Functions the same as the <> (Not Equal To) comparison operator."

Comment: @Doug: it says: *Functions the same as the <> (Not Equal To) comparison operator*. Why stop using the standard operator and use the non-standard instead?

Comment: <br/> My point is != is far more debugger friendly than saying everything is less than or greater than

Comment: @Doug - How is `!=` more friendly than `<>` when `<>` enjoys _much_ better cross-platform support?

Comment: how is INT(1) <> Date('April 4,2011')?  read that statement as plain english and it makes no sense...plus i've used != in every comparison since 2001 and I've never had an issue.

Comment: @Doug: what does "debugger friendly" mean?

Comment: @cdeszaq : Ha, we all know that if someone is using vb.net they are not worried about other platforms...me included.

Comment: @Quassnoi : I was referring to the person doing the debugging. the 'debugger'

Comment: @Doug: now you're inventing new meanings for the words. How is the person who makes bugs called? Oh, nevermind.

Comment: @Quassnoi : The person who makes the bugs?  That is an easy one.  The developer. ;)

Comment: @Doug: do you realize that calling him a developer disproves your point about the wrong operator used?

Answer (score 0):

One important thing to take into consideration when dealing with querying based on date is that the date in SQL Server is treated as exact as the date you send in. So, if you pass in a full date/time, like `2011-10-24 14:35:29`, it will return all dates that are *not* that *exact* date. If you are looking for a particular portion of that date to be selected against, you need to only give that portion of the date. Using the `DATEPART` command will help here also.

Answer (score 0):

If the value is undefined, it is not included in <> or != clause.
Along with these you can use sql function 'COALESCE()' to include rows having undefined cells.

```
   "SELECT * FROM [Products] WHERE COALESCE([ParkingStartDate],'') <> @StartDate OR ParkingStartDate is null"
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to try with NULLIF operator. Modify your query to be like :

```
SELECT * FROM [Products] WHERE NULLIF([ParkingStartDate], @StartDate) IS NOT NULL  OR ParkingStartDate is NULL
```

Hope this helps.